# CSS styling specific category (change logo/title)

Tags: css, wordpress, styling

I have created an alias domain to my old blog https://londonim.co.il/ so it will handle on the cycling related content under the domain: https://cyclondon.co.uk
I have managed to change the logo to the new hompage by creating a static page (and redirecting any traffic from https://cyclondon.co.uk to it.)
I have used this CCS:

```
/*cycling */

.page-id-3811 .cutewp-logo-img-link {
   content: url(https://londonim.co.il/logo_cycle.png);
}
```

My question is as followed:
when i try to give any post from "cycling" category the same logo, nothing seems to open.
this is the code that is not working:

```
.category-cycling .cutewp-logo-img-link {
   content: url(https://londonim.co.il/logo_cycle.png);
}
```

And also a followup if you may:
no matter what I do, whether i used cyclondon.co.uk or londonim.co.il I am getting the same website title from the Wordpress definition. Is there a way to define a custom web title for a specific page, similarly like changing the logo?

Many many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried throwing an `!important` on the end -

```
.category-cycling .cutewp-logo-img-link {
   content: url(https://londonim.co.il/logo_cycle.png)!important;
}
```

Comment: any other ideas?  to change the logo at a post i simply do `.postid-xxx` surely i am missing anything in the category css...?